# Logon Failure: the target account name is incorrect after making a ghost image of a server

Tags: windows, active-directory, replication, windows-server-2000

I recently replaced a failing SCSI drive in a Windows 2000 server with an IDE drive. I made an image of the SCSI drive and Ghosted it.  The purpose of the machine was to give out DHCP at one location and host a couple of files.

When I restarted the machine with the new drive, DHCP appears to be working fine, but I cannot get to any of the shares.  Instead, I get the following message when attempting to navigate to the rebuilt server from any other computer using Windows Explorer.

Logon Failure: the target account name is incorrect

Also, when running NET VIEW \\servername I get System Error 5 has Occurred. Access Denied.

It appears that this machine is not communicating with the main domain controller.  Changes to user accounts (performed on the domain controller) are not replicated on this machine.

EDIT - clarification

EDIT - System Logs shows Failed to Authenticate

Comment: Can you clarify whether you're getting that error from the rebuilt machine itself or from a workstation accessing it?

Comment: Are there any errors in the System or Application Logs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried resetting the machine account in the domain and/or removing it from the domain and joining it back?

Comment: thanks for the advice. I am trying that now and will report back.

Comment: dcpromo fixed the problem

Comment: ...dcpromo?!?!?

Answer (score 0):

I get random weirdness like this sometimes on my machines, and it turns out to be that DNS has gotten confused.

If I do a `nslookup` on the machine I get the *Login Failure* error message for, it will return a different host name (often one I've chucked out a few months ago) but the same IP address.

Going into the DNS MMC snap in and removing the offending records, then doing `ipconfig /release` `ipconfig /renew` on the client for good meausres usually does the trick for me.

Answer (score 0):

I've also came to the issue `Logon Failure: The target account name is incorrect` after adding to domain cloned VMWare VM.

It was sufficient to just regenerate virtual network adapter's MAC and reboot VM to resolve the problem.